# Entity Framework Core Relationship Issue (code first) - duplicate columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm doing an app with code first approach (EF Core 5 + SQL Server).

I have some tables with data and then 2 connecting tables.

The issue I have is that EF somehow creates duplicate columns in the connecting tables. For ex. SessionId and than also SessionId1. I have no idea why.

Here are some snippets from the code for better understanding:

Session table:

```
    public class Session
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public long EventId { get; set; }

        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
        public virtual UserSessionRole UserSessionRole { get; set; }
    }
```

Event table:

```
    public class Event
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    }
```

Connecting table:

```
    public class UserSessionRole
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long SessionId { get; set; }
        public long RoleId { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public long EventId { get; set; }

        public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
        public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

I used fluent API to define relationships etc. Ex. of Session settings:

```
// Map entities to tables  
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().ToTable("sessions");

            // Configure Primary Keys  
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().HasKey(u => u.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            // Configure indexes  
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().HasIndex(u => u.EventId);

            // Configure columns  
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().Property(ug => ug.Name).HasColumnType("nvarchar(255)").IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().Property(ug => ug.Description).HasColumnType("nvarchar(255)").IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().Property(ug => ug.DateTime).HasColumnType("datetime").IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().Property(ug => ug.VonageSessionId).HasColumnType("nvarchar(255)").IsRequired();

            // Configure relationships  
            modelBuilder.Entity<Session>().HasMany<UserSessionRole>().WithOne(r => r.Session).HasForeignKey(u => u.SessionId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

UserSessionRole:

```
            // Map entities to tables  
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserSessionRole>().ToTable("usersessionroles");

            // Configure Primary Keys  
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserSessionRole>().HasKey(x => new { x.RoleId, x.SessionId, x.UserId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserSessionRole>().Property(p => p.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

In this case I get duplicates of SessionId and duplicates of RoleId, but not EventId.

Anyone has an idea what did I configure wrong or if there is any trick that I don't know of?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the connection table and makes relations between Session and Event many-to-many, remove   EventId from Session, and since you are using Net5 you can add event collection to Session too

```
public class Session
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
      
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection <UserSessionRole> UserSessionRoles { get; set; }
    }
Event table:

    public class Event
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection <UserSessionRole> UserSessionRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't solve the issue, thanks.

Comment: @Skynet You have to update your fluent APIs accordingly and make an init migration again.

Answer (score 0):

With your code snippet what I can understand is you are trying to create Event and Session Table which is in One To Many Relation Ship, If So we can avoid the connection table (UserSessionRole) And Bring the RoleId, UserId to Session table.

```
public class Event
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
public class Session
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long RoleId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long EventId { get; set; }

    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

if you need the connecting table (UserSessionRole) then the relation ship become Event : UserSessionRole (one to Many) and UserSessionRole : Session (one to one) then it will become like this,

```
public class Event
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserSessionRole>SessionRoles{ get; set; }
}

// One to Many Relation between Event and UserSessionRole

public class UserSessionRole
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long EventId { get; set; }
    public long RoleId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public long SessionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
    public virtual Event Event { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

// One to One Relation between UserSessionRole and Session

public class Session
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the end by removing Event from Session and explicitly defining WithMany relationship. I also did it from the other side.

this worked:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserSessionRole>().HasOne(x => x.Event).WithMany(s => s.UserSessionRoles).HasForeignKey(u => u.EventId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

this didn't:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserSessionRole>().HasOne(x => x.Event).WithMany(s).HasForeignKey(u => u.EventId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```